# Should I uninstall Hyper-V before installing Android Emulator with HAXM on Windows 10?

Tags: android-emulator, windows-10, hyper-v, haxml

I tried to update Android Studio to the latest version and got the following errors during the update:

```
Failed to update Intel HAXM. For details, please check the installation log: "C:\Users\D-Ef\AppData\Local\Temp\haxm_log.txt"
HAXM installation failed. To install HAXM follow the instructions found at: https://software.intel.com/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows
Installer log is located at C:\Users\D-Ef\AppData\Local\Temp\haxm_log.txt
Installer log contents:
=== Logging started: 7/18/2019  1:41:09 ===
This computer does not support Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x) or it is being exclusively used by Hyper-V. HAXM cannot be installed. 
Please ensure Hyper-V is disabled in Windows Features, or refer to the Intel HAXM documentation for more information.
```

and the following in C:\Users\D-Ef\AppData\Local\Temp\haxm_log.txt:

```
=== Logging started: 7/18/2019  1:41:09 ===
This computer does not support Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x) or it is being exclusively used by Hyper-V. HAXM cannot be installed. 
Please ensure Hyper-V is disabled in Windows Features, or refer to the Intel HAXM documentation for more information.

=== Logging stopped: 7/18/2019  1:41:09 ===
```

Should I uninstall Hyper-V before installing Android Emulator with HAXM? Or there is a better solution?

Comment: you can also use Hyper-V platform for acceleration

Answer (score 1):

The on that worked for me:

1. Install Android Studio
2. Go to: Control Panel -> Turn Windows features on or off -> Disable Hyper-V
3. Disable Core isolation
4. Open Android Studio -> Configure SDK Manager -> SDK Tools -> Install HAXM